# What's the minimum invading army to leave in an occupied planet in Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

Our empire just conquered, for the first time, an enemy planet and have an army and a general controlling it.

Our commanders are debating whether to leave an army or not.

What's the minimal army that we should leave so that the population won't resist and we'll lose it to rebels?

Should we leave the general in that planet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None.

While occupied the planet will not revolt, the only risk is a reinvasion by the enemy, so feel free  to move the entire army away.

If you take the planet after the war, you may have to watch out for a rebel faction, which may eventually revolt. But you'll have enough time to react.

Comment: +1, but I *have* had the enemy try to re-invade, so depending on how spread out your war effort is, it can also be beneficial to leave a few.

Comment: Important to note that occupied planets don't generate militia -- if even a single army lands, they'll free the planet.